# How to add css for a tag with tag name?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code,

```
<div _ngcontent-hge-c9="" class="domain-button card-selected">
    <span _ngcontent-hge-c9="">1.</span>
    <span _ngcontent-hge-c9="">Benefits management</span>
    <span _ngcontent-hge-c9="" class="pull-right domain-close">x</span>
</div>
```

I want to add css to 'Benefits management' text like adding color.I tried the following,

```
.card-selected span span{
  color: white !important;
}
```

I can keep for span since I have so many span tags.

Comment: Will the span with `Benefits management` always be the second span in that div?

Comment: Look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and you can learn how to select anything in your html.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Try this:

```
.card-selected span:nth-child(2){
    color: white !important;
}
```

**EDIT for first two spans only:**

```
.card-selected span:nth-child(-n+2){
    color: white !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5kpLgnjt/

Comment: I also want for first span also,can you please add first span.

Comment: Thank you very much @lowry0031